# Is there a way to get proper "breadcrumbs" behavior in emacs?

Tags: bookmarks, navigation, breadcrumbs

I want something that I figured would be pretty basic, what with all the fancy mark-ring and all, but I can't find a way to get.

I want a global (i.e. across files) no-nonsense "breadcrumbs" behavior - that is, the ability to jump backwards (and forwards!) through the locations I visited.

I really like that locations are pushed into the ring when I search or give movement commands (I'm on spacemacs), and I would also like to have the same behavior when I jump to a new buffer, or follow links in org-mode.

I've found the breadcrumbs [package](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BreadcrumbForEmacs), but I don't know how to go about integrating the setting of those breadcrumbs in all the different movements around files (I also favor a more a solution that's more native to emacs, such as the mark-ring, but beggars can't be choosers...).

Comment: Can you clarify how what you want differs from the global mark ring? https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Global-Mark-Ring.html

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then you can [automatically create bookmarks](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#AutomaticIdle-PeriodBookmarking) for the places you visit.

Such bookmarks can be persistent (default behavior) or temporary.

> In general, you probably do not want such bookmarks to be created too often or too close together. You probably do not care about the names of the bookmarks created, and you do not want to be interrupted to name them. You probably want automatic bookmarking to be per-buffer, but you might sometimes want to turn it on or off for all buffers. You might want more than one automatic bookmark on a given line, but probably not. Finally, you might or might not want automatic bookmarks to be temporary (current session only) or highlighted.

There are user options that control all such behavior.

Comment: that sounds awesome! thanks!